# What does [....] in the middle of a quote mean?

Tags: quotes, citation

"'I'm simply defending a Negro- his name is Tom Robinson [...] Scout, you aren't old enough to understand some things yet, but there's been some high talk around town to the effect that I shouldn't do much about defending this man.'" -To Kill a Mockingbird (page 100)

Comment: Just a note to add that a "duplicate" question doesn't have to be an exact match, but the linked question does answer this one.

Answer (score 2):

The [...] means that some content has been removed there to make the quote more readable and flow better.

Comment: Under the academic system I have used (which I think is the Oxford system), three dots would be sufficient to indicate removed material. Square brackets are usually placed around words which are outside the quotation; added to provide information, or for the quotation to make better grammatical or general sense to the reader.